# Rewinding iteration

Tags: python, iteration

I've been looping through the contents of a list in the simple fashion to take user input:

```
for n in [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]:
 command = raw_input ( "%d >> " % (n) )
 ...
```

I want to implement an undo feature, which would mean "rewinding" the iteration back to the previous value. Here is a naive way which does decrease the value of n, but then skips the original value because the internal pointer into the list isn't altered:

```
for n in [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]:
 if f(n):
  n -= 1
 ...
```

In the docs I see an iterator.next(), but no iterator.last(). I think I could switch to accessing list members by integer index and hand-roll the loop by manipulating the index myself, which isn't all that threatening, but is there a better way?

Comment: You'll have to implement it yourself (save the last 5-10 items yourself), it's not possible to "rewind" an iterator. Also, it's a duplicate of [Making a python iterator go backwards?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2777188/236871)

Comment: I think you can use `while` loop to implement this.

Comment: He said he had a "list", i don't think would actually use a `range(1, 5)` list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `While` loop:

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4]
i = 0
while i < len(lis):
    if some_condition:
        print(lis[i])
        i += 1
    elif some_other_condition:
        print(lis[i])
        i -= 1
```

Comment: thank you very much ashwini, that looks quite reasonable (and easy).

Answer (score 9):

There's no obvious way to do this in stock Python, but it's easy enough to make your own iterator that supports backtracking. For example, a "seekable" iterator follows. Seek relative 0 to repeat the same element, or relative -1 to go back to previous element.

NB because this style of iteration doesn't enjoy "guaranteed forward progress," it's arguably more prone to infinite loops.

```
class SeekableIterator(object):
    """An iterator that supports seeking backwards or forwards."""

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        """Make a SeekableIterator over an iterable collection."""

        self.iterable = iterable
        self.index = None

    def __iter__(self):
        """Start the iteration."""

        self.index = 0
        return self

    def next(self):
        """Return the next item in the iterator."""

        try:
            value = self.iterable[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return value
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration

    def seek(self, n, relative=False):
        """Adjust the loop counter, either relatively or to an absolute index.
        Note that seeking 0 replays the current item. Seeking -1 goes to
        the previous item. If the adjustment pushes the index outside the
        iterable's bounds, raise an index error."""

        if relative:
            self.index += n - 1
            # NB index already advanced one in next(), so subtracting one here
        else:
            self.index = n
        if self.index < 0 or self.index >= len(self.iterable):
            raise IndexError


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import random

    def prob(percent):
        """Return True with roughly the given probability, else False"""
        return random.random() <= (percent * 1.0 / 100.0)

    seeker = SeekableIterator([1, 2, 3, 4])
    for n in seeker:
        print "n:", n

        if prob(50):
            if prob(50):
                print "\tREDO - seeking 0"
                seeker.seek(0, relative=True)
            elif n > 1:
                print "\tUNDO - seeking -1"
                seeker.seek(-1, relative=True)
```

Here is an example output:

```
n: 1
n: 2
n: 3
n: 4
    REDO - seeking 0
n: 4
    REDO - seeking 0
n: 4
    UNDO - seeking -1
n: 3
n: 4
```

Comment: very general, pythonic, and you're absolutely right about the forward progress. thank you jonathan.

Comment: In this implementation, seeking doesn't appear to do anything if `relative=True` isn't passed in.

Answer (score 1):

The consensus is that no, there is no way to make a python iterator backtrack.  This thread has more information:

[Making a python iterator go backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards)

However, you might have some luck restructuring your loop to be of a slightly different format.  Consider the following pythonlike pseudocode:

```
unprocessed = [1,2,3,...]
processed = []

traverse(unprocessed, processed, processor_function):
    item = unprocessed.head()
    unprocessed = unprocessed.tail()
    processed.prepend(item)
    if processor_function != None:
        processor_function(item)
```

Your primary loop logic can, if necessary, call traverse in either order, switching processed and unprocessed in order to emulate iterating backwards.  You can pass whatever processing function you want, including passing `None` to simply skip processing.  when you have finished processing all of the elements, the lists will look like this:

```
unprocessed = []
processed = [...,3,2,1]
```

It's sort of turing-machine-esque.  The "read head" is always above the first element of the first list, all elements to the "right" of the read head are in the first list with index ascending with distance, and all elements to the "left" of the read hear are in the second list, with index ascending with distance.  The elements "closest" to the read head are those close to the beginning of each list.