# python - How to move back an iteration in a for loop list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Given the list: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4 5]` in a `for` loop, suppose that the current item is 2, and next item is 3. If some condition is true, how can I make the next item be 2 again, which means the iteration should continue from 2 again instead of 3?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in a:
   print item
   if condition:
         do something, and go back to previous iterator
```

The output would be:

```
1
2
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: That duplicate's solution is needlessly general because it deals with the mechanics of iterators in general. For a list this could easily be done with a `while` loop instead of `for`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What does the condition depend on? Do you have to reach 3 to determine that you have to use 2 again?

Comment: [See here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards), if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of an infinite loop, and it's not very Pythonic.

```
i = 0
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
hasBeenReset = False
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] == 3 and not hasBeenReset:
        i = 1
        hasBeenReset = True
    print(a[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: This code is an infinite loop.

Comment: I updated to do the output just like in the example in the original question.