# Lookahead or retractable iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I need to extract all words in a text that match a certain criterion, e.g. appear in some dictionary.

```
some_dict = set()    # initialize from file

def test1(word):
    return word in some_dict

def extract1(text):
    return [word for word in text.split() if test1(word)]
```

Yeah, but some entries in the dictionary consist of several words, up to 4.

```
MAX_DEPTH = 4

def extract2(text):
    words = text.split()
    return [word for i, word in enumerate(words) if test2(words[i:i + MAX_DEPTH])]

def test2(words):
    for phrase in (' '.join(words[:i]) for i in range(1, len(words))):
        if phrase in some_dict:
            return True
    return False
```

Oh, but I need the whole phrase and not just the first word, so

```
def extract3(text):
    words = text.split()
    res = []
    for i in range(len(words)):
        matched = test3(words[i:i + MAX_DEPTH])
        if matched:
            res.append(matched)
    return res

def test3(words):
    for phrase in (' '.join(words[:i]) for i in range(1, len(words))):
        if phrase in some_dict:
            return phrase
    return None
```

Well, but if a multi-word phrase matched I need to skip it and NOT to test its other words, even if they appear as separate words in the dictionary. So I need a retractable iterator.
This is my attempt to implement one:

```
from copy import copy

def extract4(text):
    words = text.split()
    res = []
    it = iter(words)
    try:
        while True:
            matched, it = test4(it)
            if matched:
                res.append(matched)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    return res

def test4(it):
    words = [next(it)]  # will raise StopIteration when the list is exhausted
    save = copy(it)
    try:
        for _ in range(MAX_DEPTH):
            phrase = ' '.join(words)
            if phrase in some_dict:
                return phrase, it   # skip the phrase
            words.append(next(it))
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    return None, save # retract
```

I am a bit concerned with possible performance implications of creating a copy of the iterator for each word in the text as it may be quite long. And in general, can this be improved, both style- and performance-wise?

EDIT:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards) proposes solutions for bidirectional iterator, but I'd rather have the client use standard iterators

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a python iterator go backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards)

Comment: @Phylogenesis I address this in the edit