# Jump back in python iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

What's the most effective way to do something like this C code

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(i == 5)
        i = 1;
}
```

in python, so the output would be

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
```

I know there is for in range with next()

```
iterator = iter(range(0, 10))
for i in iterator:
    next(iterator)
    print(i)
```

so this code would print every second number, but I don't know how to jump back in for loop.

Comment: you can't rewind an iterator. Why are you calling `next()`? The for loop calls next() for you automatically.

Comment: Why not use a while loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but many approaches ? You could use a while loop with True and incrementing i by 1 then reset it at 5. You can write the exact same C code in Python too

Comment: This is a duplicate of this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards

In other news, how do I report something as being a duplicate?

And then finally to answer the question, I would just use a while loop.  You could also break and start iteration again from the desired position.

Comment: @Azsgy I know that for loop is calling next automatically, I wanted to demonstrate an example with next, because I wanted something similar but prev(iterator)

Comment: @TravisBlack Click `flag`, then choose "duplicate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realize from the comments that I have to use while loop in the way like this

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
    if i == 5:
        i = 1
```

The example above with itertools and chain is nice, but I wanted some solution like this while cycle, but I wasn't thinking about while. In my code, there are some more complex conditions, not only this easy "chain", but I thought that it will be enough for a demonstration of "jump".

Answer (score 7):

You can loop forever using [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and you can use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to append the starting condition like:

```
import itertools as it
for i in it.chain((0,), it.cycle(range(1, 6))):
    print(i)
```

#### Results:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: @OP, Since this code will run indefinitely, you can setup a separate break condition inside the for loop.

Comment: Thank you but this was the very specifical example, I wanted something more general, like setting actual value of iterator, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen I try without chain and work well. thks nice code

```
import itertools as it
for i in it.cycle(range(1, 6)):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce much of the C style for loop using an iterator class.

For example:

```
class cFor:   
    def __init__(self,start,condition,step=1):
        self.index     = start
        self.nextIndex = start
        self.doLoop    = condition
        if type(condition) == type(start):
            self.doLoop  = lambda x:x < condition
        self.getNext   = step
        if type(step) == type(start):
            self.getNext = lambda x:x + step

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self) : return self.__next__()

    def __next__(self):
        if self.doLoop(self.nextIndex):
            self.index     = self.nextIndex
            self.nextIndex = self.getNext(self.index)
            return self.index
        raise StopIteration()
```

This will allow you to perform simple loops:

```
for i in cFor(0,10,2) : print(i)
# 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
```

and, using lambdas, you can provide your own condition and increment calculation:

```
for i in cFor(1, lambda i:i<=10, lambda i:i+3): print(i)
# 1, 4, 7, 10
```

or apply more complex "inline" calculations :

```
[ a for a,b in cFor((1,1),lambda ab:ab[1]<30,lambda ab:(ab[1],sum(ab))) ]
# [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 ]
```

To be able to modify the index (or condition or increment) within the loop, you could create a generator function that returns both the current index and the iterator instance.  This will let you take control of the iterator's properties within the loop body.

```
def cForLoop(start,condition,step=1):
    loop = cFor(start,condition,step)
    while True : yield loop.next(), loop

for i,loop in cForLoop(0,10):
    print(i)
    if i == 5 : loop.nextIndex = 1
# 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....
```

you could, for example, use this to implement a simple bubble sort:

```
arr = [3,7,4,2,8,1,6]

for i,loop in cForLoop(1,len(arr)):
    if arr[i-1] > arr[i] :
        arr[i],arr[i-1] = arr[i-1],arr[i]
        loop.nextIndex = max(1,i-1) 

# arr == [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```